# slonik- Module '"slonik"' has no exported member 'InterceptorType'

Tags: node.js, slonik

after updating slonik I got this error

```
[ERROR] 00:03:35 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
lib/newrelic/instrumentSlonik.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"slonik"' has no exported member 'InterceptorType'.

node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/log.js:27
```

any hint where to start from